# how to run a c program with reading command line parameters in openvms?

Tags: c, openvms, vms

I built a simple program try to print the command line parameters.

The code is below and I built an executable file (TEST.EXE).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
    for (i = 1;  i < argc;  i++)
       printf("argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I try to run the TEST.EXE and print the parameters but fail.

The result of command `RUN TEST.EXE test1 test2`:

```
%DCL-W-MAXPARM, too many parameters - reenter command with fewer parameters
```

What can I do to print "test1" and "test2"?

Comment: This simple question makes VMS look like a dinosaur.  No wonder other OSes took over.  VMS had nice file system goodies, but it was never meant to run programs interactively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition, if you need to preserve the case of the arguments, you have to quote these arguments or enter

```
$ SET PROCESS/PARSE_STYLE=EXTENDED
```

once in the lifetime of your process and

```
$ DEFINE/USER DECC$ARGV_PARSE_STYLE TRUE
```

before running your program with a specific foreign command or by using automatic foreign commands (DCL$PATH). Otherwise all the unquoted arguments are converted to lowercase characters.

PS: VMS has a command language, that is, you have to enter a command to run a program. By default, file names are no commands. With defining DCL$PATH you  change this default behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

The `RUN` command doesn't support any command line arguments. Define a foreign command and use that instead. From David Mathog's [beginner FAQ](http://saf.bio.caltech.edu/vms_beginners_faq.html#PROC06):

> How do I start a program?
>
> - **Method 2:**  Use the `RUN` command:
>
>   `$ run program_name`*`No command line arguments allowed`*
> - **Method 3:**  Define a foreign command for it, then run it.  In the
>     following
>            example where is a logical name equivalent to the
>            location of the program.
>
>   `$ new_command :== $where:program_name`
>     `$ new_command [command line arguments]`

Answer (score 4):

Defining a foreign command as per 'a3f' is the 'proper' way to do it albeit somewhat tedious and 2-stepped.

You may also want to try the MCR 'trick'.
MCR being short for the Monitor Command Routine from the 40+ year old PDPD-11 Operating System RSX.

Now MCR defaults to look for program in SYS$SYSTEM, so you do have to specify the current location:

```
$ MCR dev:[dir]TEST this is a test.
```

There is also a 1-1/2 step approach using DCL$PATH.
This works mostly like the Unix and Windows path, providing places to look for DCL scripts or programs if an unknown command is entered.

For example

```
$ DEFINE DCL$PATH SYS$DISK:[],SYS$LOGIN:,SYS$SYSTEM:
```

Now just type : `TEST this.`

Hein