# Running a program with parameters in DCL and saving the output

Tags: openvms, dcl

I'm trying to run a program and get the output value in DCL.

In Linux platform script like below

```
result=$(./tool -e $parameter1 $parameter2 )
echo "result:" $result
```

I try to do the same script in HP openVMS platform but fail.

Could anyone provide a sample or give me some tips?

Thanks a lot.

**Reference:**
[How to assign the output of a program to a variable in a DCL com script on VMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431757/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-in-a-dcl-com-script-on-vms)

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of your "tool"? As long as it is one line, the answer to a similar, recent question [How to store a result to a variable in HP OpenVMS DCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890693/how-to-store-a-result-to-a-variable-in-hp-openvms-dcl) may help. Other than that, using a pipe command with a temporary output file is probably the easiest solution. Something like

```
$ PIPE tool -e argument1 argument2 >tmp.txt
$ TYPE tmp.txt
```

In case you don't know how to pass arguments to your "tool", see [how to run a c program with reading command line parameters in openvms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532928/how-to-run-a-c-program-with-reading-command-line-parameters-in-openvms)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect sys$output in OpenVMS, you can do

1) `$ define/user sys$output file.lis`

This means that for the next image activation, the output will go in file.lis

For example, the command

`mc authorize sh system`

will just give back the prompt
if you issue a second time

`mc authorize sh system`

it will be displayed "normally", on the screen

A variant is

`define sys$output file.lis
my_command
my_other_command
deassign sys$output`

The output of all your commands goes to file.lis until you deassign sys$output

2) `@my_script.com/output=file.lis`

You run your OpenVMS script and the output goes to file.lis

3) `@tt:/output=file.lis
@myscript
CTRL Z`

to exit
is similar to 2)

This was used to exit "captive command procedure"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check the value of the $STATUS DCL variable.